# How I can encode with Protobuf a Cypress stub response?

Tags: cypress, protobuf.js

I have some fixtures to stub a server that encode the messages with protobuf (I'm using `protobufjs`). I'd like to have the fixtures decoded to easily manipulate them and let Cypress encode the stub body before sending the response to the client, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UPDATE] it's now available as a [Cypress plugin](https://github.com/NoriSte/cypress-protobuf)

---

That's my solution:

- `cypress/plugins/protobufjs/index.js` file (where the protobuf definitions are imported)

```
const path = require("path");
const protobufjs = require("protobufjs");
const definition = path.join(__dirname, "../../../public/escrow/ui.proto");
const proto = protobufjs.loadSync(definition);
module.exports = {
  Status: proto.lookupType("escrow.Status"),
};
```

- `cypress/plugins/index.js` file (where the encoding happens with a custom Cypress task)

```
const { StringDecoder } = require("string_decoder");
const Messages = require("./protobufjs");

module.exports = on => {
  on("task", {
    protobufEncode: ({ data, encoderName }) => {
      const decoder = new StringDecoder("utf8");
      const bufferValue = Messages[encoderName].encode(data).finish();
      return decoder.end(Buffer.from(bufferValue));
    }
  });
};
```

- in your test

```
cy.fixture("YOUR_FIXTURE.json").then(async json => {
  cy.task("protobufEncode", { encoderName: "Status", data: json }).then(result => {
    cy.route({
      headers: {
        "content-type": "application/octet-stream"
      },
      method: "GET",
      response: result,
      status: 200,
      url: `**/YOUR_URL`
    }).as("route_status_one_usb_key");
  });
});
```